# Shows timer (minutes and seconds) in console

Tags: c#, timer, stopwatch

I need shows the timer running in console. I use stopwatch:

System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

```
public void startTime()
{
    stopwatch.Start();
}

public void GetTime(){
    stopwatch.Stop();
    TimeSpan timeSpan = stopwatch.Elapsed;
    var timeElapsed = (string.Format("\nTime Elapsed: {0} minute(s) {1} second(s)",
    timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds, timeSpan.Milliseconds / 10 + "\n")).ToString();
}
```

I need shows in console the timer running normally: 00:00:01, 00:00:02, 00:00:03 ... etc

How can I do this?

Comment: why are you stopping it when you get the time?

Comment: this is for get the time elapsed. But I need shows the time running and then stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

while (true)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    Console.Write(sw.Elapsed.ToString("g"));

    if (sw.Elapsed.TotalMinutes > 30)
        break;
}
```

Comment: how can I put the timer wherever withoud the SetCursorPosition? and what is the meaning of "g"??

Comment: Set cursor is required as you need to overwrite what was written before. The `g` is the name of a TimeSpan formatter. see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx

Comment: I need shows only the minutes and seconds. how can I do this here?

Comment: you can change the `g` into `mm\\:ss` to get minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 2):

see

```
Console.Clear
```

and

```
Console.SetCursorPosition
```

methods